# Set up camera on the background of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I'm trying set camera on the background of UIView in UIViewController, in order to be able to draw on it.

How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATED TO SWIFT 5**

You could try something like this:

I add two `UIView`s to my `UIViewController`'s main view, one called `previewView` (for the camera) and another `UIView` called `boxView` (which is above the camera view)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var previewView : UIView!
    var boxView:UIView!

    //Camera Capture requiered properties
    var videoDataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
    var videoDataOutputQueue: DispatchQueue!
    var previewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var currentFrame: CIImage!
    var done = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        previewView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
        previewView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(previewView)

        //Add a box view
        boxView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
        boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        boxView.alpha = 0.3
        view.addSubview(boxView)

        self.setupAVCapture()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if !done {
            session.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        if (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft ||
        UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight ||
            UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.unknown) {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
}


// AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate protocol and related methods
extension ViewController:  AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{
    func setupAVCapture(){
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.vga640x480
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice
        .default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                 for: .video,
                 position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front) else{
                            return
        }
        captureDevice = device
        beginSession()
        done = true
    }

    func beginSession(){
        var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            guard deviceInput != nil else {
                print("error: cant get deviceInput")
                return
            }

            if self.session.canAddInput(deviceInput){
                self.session.addInput(deviceInput)
            }

            videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames=true
            videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoDataOutputQueue")
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue:self.videoDataOutputQueue)

            if session.canAddOutput(self.videoDataOutput){
                session.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
            }

            videoDataOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)?.isEnabled = true

            self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
            self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect

            let rootLayer: CALayer = self.previewView.layer
            rootLayer.masksToBounds = true
            self.previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
            rootLayer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
            session.startRunning()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            deviceInput = nil
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        currentFrame =   self.convertImageFromCMSampleBufferRef(sampleBuffer)
    }


    // clean up AVCapture
    func stopCamera(){
        session.stopRunning()
        done = false
    }

    func convertImageFromCMSampleBufferRef(_ sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> CIImage{
        let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
        let ciImage:CIImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        return ciImage
    }
}
```

You can replace the boxView's `frame` with mainView's `frame`and don't set its background property. This way you can use this view to add more subviews.

> **IMPORTANT**
>
> *Remember that in iOS 10 you need to first ask the user for permission in order to have access to the camera. You do this by adding a **usage
>   key** to your app’s `Info.plist` together with a **purpose string**
>   because if you fail to declare the usage, your app will crash when it
>   first makes the access.*

Here's a screenshot to show the Camera access request

[image]

I hope this can help!

Comment: By the way, I like your solutions. Thanks!

Comment: works for me too! thanks you save me...

Answer (score 4):

An other way, SceneView is useful for augmented reality applications.

1. Create a preview layer with AVFramework or UIView, then add preview
   layer to view's sublayer.
2. Create and custumize a sceneview. Then add sceneview to view's
   subview.
3. Create and custimize scene. Finally add to scenview's scene.

   ```
       // 1. Create a preview layer with AVFramework or UIView, then add preview layer to view's sublayer.
       self.previewLayer!.frame = view.layer.bounds
       view.clipsToBounds = true
       view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer!)



       // 2. Create and custumize a sceneview. Then add sceneview to view's subview.
       let sceneView = SCNView()
       sceneView.frame = view.bounds
       sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
       self.previewLayer!.frame = view.bounds
       view.addSubview(sceneView)

       //   3 . Create and custimize scene. Finally add to scenview's scene.
       let scene = SCNScene()
       sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
       sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
       let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 800 , height: 400, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 1.0)
       let yellow = UIColor.yellowColor()
       let semi = yellow.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
       boxGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = semi
       let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
       scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
       sceneView.scene = scene
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way of doing this is to add overlay view on imagepickercontroller and hide the default view.

The other way is to use AV framework that will give you much more options and freedom.

Choice depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you . Can you post the link with an example, please?